# Android - best way to remember date

Tags: java, android, date, save

What is the best way to remember date? I mean, I want to save last date when the app was started. I want use this information to check if the app wasn't ran for longer than one day. I was thinking about saving date in .txt file but maybe there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can save it in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putInt("lastStartTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
// Commit the edits!
editor.commit();
```

Comment: By the way, `editor.apply()` is faster than `editor.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way to do it. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

While you could save the milliseconds count-from-epoch as the serialized value, I don't recommend that. Humans cannot easily understand the date-time meaning of a 64-bit integer number, so debugging is made more difficult.

If you want a more human-readable value, I suggest using the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

Example: `2015-04-01T08:41:51+02:00`

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library generates and parses such strings by default. If you do much work at all with date-time, I strongly suggest learning how to use Joda-Time rather than the troublesome and flawed java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with Java (and Android). Joda-Time does work in Android.

## UTC

Generally the best practice is to convert your date-time value to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) when storing. At runtime, adjust to a desired time zone as expected by the user.

Example UTC value, where offset is set to zero.

```
2015-04-01T06:41:51+00:00
```